# Subscribe to slice of store - ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

Using latest **NgRx** with entity adapter
I'm trying to subscribe only to a slice of the entities array using selectors.

Problem is that no matter what change has occurred in the state the selector is firing.

Example:
User store

```
Ids:string[]
Users:{}

Selector example
SelectUsereAged18 = createSelector(
    SelectAllUsers,
    (Users:User[])=>Users.filter(user=>user.age>18)
)
```

Now even if a new user aged 15 is upserted to the array the selector will fire...

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is the desired result, a user from `SelectAllUsers` is modified thus the selector has to re-calculate a new result. Since the returned users from `selectUserAged18` are still the same, other selectors using this selector shouldn't re-calculate their output.

Comment: So the only option is to subscribe directly to specific users by id's?

Comment: If you add a user it will still "fire", if you update a user it won't.

Comment: If you have a reproduction I could take a look